# How to mapping from the value of one alist entry to the value of another entry of the same alist

Tags: interactive

I have a data structure like:
`((fid . FID) (name . NAME) (count . COUNT) (data . ORIGINAL_DATA))`

I have following Elisp code try to interactively select `FID` through display
the `NAME` instead of `FID`.

```el
(defun emms-bilibili-favlist-select ()
  "Interactive select which favlist to open."
  (let* ((fav-name (completing-read "Select favlist: "
                                    (mapcar
                                     (lambda (x) (alist-get 'name x))
                                     (emms-bilibili--retrieve-favfolder))))
         ;; TODO:
         (favlist ...)
         )
    (emms-bilibili--retrieve-favlist (alist-get 'fid favlist))))
```

I need it to display a list in interactive select:

`NAME A
NAME B
NAME C`

When I select "NAME A", code need to get the corresponding `FID`. (upper code is
just my pseudo code, if you have better solution, please tell me, Thanks.)

Comment: Your title does not seem to represent your question. "How to interactively select alist cons pair's cdr instead of whole cons" seems to be a problem that you have successfully solved already by using `alist-get` instead of `assq`. Your actual question seems to be about mapping from the value of one alist entry to the value of another entry of the same alist.  Can you please clarify the title/question to make them consistent?

Comment: Sorry about this, I did considered the question title, but don't know how to describe it. I will update the title now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can ensure names are unique, you can lookup the list of
alist through `NAME` to get the corresponding `FID`, for example,

```el
(let* ((alists
        '(((fid . 1) (name . "Name A"))
          ((fid . 2) (name . "Name B"))
          ((fid . 3) (name . "Name C"))))
       (name
        (completing-read
         "> "
         (mapcar
          (lambda (al) (alist-get 'name al))
          alists)))
       (alist
        (seq-find
         (lambda (al)
           (string= name (alist-get 'name al)))
         alists)))
  (alist-get 'fid alist))
```